# How to plot a graph using this data with python?

Tags: python, plot, graph

I want to create time series plot using max, min and avg temperatures from each month of the year.

Comment: can you be more specific plz , there is a library named matplotlib for plot graph

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html) to visualize different types of data which can be installed with a quick `pip3 install matplotlib`.

Here is some starter code you can play around with to get familiar with the library:

```
# Import the library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some sample data to play around with
temps = [30,40,45,50,55,60]
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]

# Create a figure and plot the data
plt.figure()
plt.plot(temps)

# Add labels to the data points (optional)
for i, point in enumerate(months):
    plt.annotate(point, (i, temps[i]))

# Apply some labels
plt.ylabel("Temperature (F)")
plt.title("Temperature Plot")

# Hide the x axis labels 
plt.gca().axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

# Show the comlpeted plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31'),
                   'Temp':np.random.randint(20, 100, 365)})

df.head()
        Date  Temp
0 2010-01-01    95
1 2010-01-02    20
2 2010-01-03    22
3 2010-01-04    26
4 2010-01-05    93

# group by month and get min, max, mean values for temperature
temp_agg = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month)['Temp'].agg([min, max, np.mean])
temp_agg.index.name='month'

temp_agg
       min  max       mean
month                     
1       20   99  50.258065
2       25   98  56.642857
3       22   89  51.225806
4       22   98  60.333333
5       27   99  57.645161
6       21   99  62.000000
7       20   98  67.419355
8       36   98  63.806452
9       22   99  62.166667
10      24   99  63.322581
11      22   97  64.200000
12      20   99  60.870968

# shorthand method of plotting entire dataframe
temp_agg.plot()
```

[image]